# XML Serializer - Hide Element

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

Good Afternoon,

I have the following code:

```
public class PurchaseOrder
{
    public Item [] Items
}
public class Item
{
    public string ItemID
    public decimal ItemPrice
}
```

when serialized, this generates the following XML:

```
<PurchaseOrder xmlns:xsi=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    **<Items>**
        <Item>
            <ItemID>aaa111</ItemID>
            <ItemPrice>34.22</ItemPrice>
        <Item>
        <Item>
            <ItemID>bbb222</ItemID>
            <ItemPrice>2.89</ItemPrice>
        <Item>
    **</Items>**
</PurchaseOrder>
```

Is there any way of omitting the `<Items>` `</Items>` element (in bold) - but continue to include the `<Item>` element?

Comment: Last time i ran into that problem I had to implement `IXmlSerializable` and do the array serialization manually because otherwise the `XmlSerializer` would generate/read empty XML elements or empty objects while (de)serializing an array...

Answer (score 1):

If you use a list rather than an array, as follows:

```
public class PurchaseOrder
{
    [XmlElement("Item")]
    public List<Item> Items;
}
public class Item
{
    public string ItemID;
    public decimal ItemPrice;
}
```

Will produce:

```
<PurchaseOrder xmlns:xsi=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Item>
        <ItemID>aaa111</ItemID>
        <ItemPrice>34.22</ItemPrice>
    <Item>
    <Item>
        <ItemID>bbb222</ItemID>
        <ItemPrice>2.89</ItemPrice>
    <Item>
</PurchaseOrder>
```

Comment: @JoelH If this answers your question, could you click the tick at the top left of the answer.  If it does not tell me why. Thanks